# Partially annotate django queryset

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a query that looks like that

```py
TrendData.objects.filter(owner__trend_type__mnemonic='posts').filter(
            date_trend__date__range=[date_from, date_to]).order_by(sort_by)[0: 100].values(
        'owner__name',
        'owner_id',
        'owner__link',
    ).annotate(
        owner_count=Count('owner_id')).annotate(views=Sum('views'), views_u=Sum('views_u'),
                                                likes=Sum('likes'),
                                                shares=Sum('shares'),
                                                interaction_rate=Sum('interaction_rate'),
                                                mean_age=Sum('mean_age')
                                                )
```

It was worse before, however I have noticed that annotation sums ALL the values in queryset, not the limited queryset that I set before annotation.

Is it possible to annotate only partially , the amount I have limited.
My RAW query looks like this

```sql
'SELECT "api_trenddata"."id", "api_trenddata"."owner_id",  
 "api_trenddata"."views", "api_trenddata"."views_u",  
 "api_trenddata"."likes", "api_trenddata"."shares",  
 "api_trenddata"."interaction_rate", "api_trenddata"."mean_age",  
 "api_trenddata"."source_id", "api_trenddata"."date_trend",  
 SUM("api_trenddata"."views") AS "views", SUM("api_trenddata"."views_u") AS "views_u",  
 SUM("api_trenddata"."likes") AS "likes", SUM("api_trenddata"."shares") AS "shares", SUM("api_trenddata"."interaction_rate") AS  
 "interaction_rate", SUM("api_trenddata"."mean_age")  
 AS "mean_age" FROM "api_trenddata" INNER JOIN "api_owner" ON  
 ("api_trenddata"."owner_id" = "api_owner"."id") INNER JOIN  
 "api_trendtype" ON ("api_owner"."trend_type_id" =  
 "api_trendtype"."id") 
 WHERE ("api_trendtype"."mnemonic" = posts   AND("api_trenddata"."date_trend" AT TIME ZONE \'UTC\')::date BETWEEN 2019 04-05 AND 2019-04-06) GROUP BY "api_trenddata"."id"'
```

Comment: Why not put the `[:100]` part at the end?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem my queryset could be as big as 1m entries, if date range long enough, so it will be sort of as a offset and limit for a queryset.
So i dont want annotating the whole queryset , just the limited part of it, if that's possible

Comment: @nexia: but that will not make any difference at all. The processing is not done effectively in the order you specify it. A limit will cut off the results from the moment it reaches the limit.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem actually more or less the same result(using```time```) showed equally bad result when I iterate through, but I figured the problem is annotation, it adds those 2 seconds(almost exactly)

Comment: Not exactly related to the issue you're experiencing, but it was my understanding [from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) that chaining filter calls like you have results in an `OR` in the `WHERE` clause as opposed to an `AND`

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated): "even though slicing an unevaluated QuerySet returns another unevaluated QuerySet, modifying it further (e.g., adding more filters, or modifying ordering) is not allowed".  Can you use a calculated filter instead of order->slice?

Comment: The easiest and most efficient way might be to get the sliced array in a list and use `functools.reduce` to compute the sums in memory